# Singly Linked List in C (Warning)

Tags: c

I am trying to implement singly linked list. Is this correct? Getting this warning "non portable pointer conversion". How do i check if the SLL is working? Is it connected to each other? By the way, I am using Turbo C. I am still in this creating and inserting the nodes part.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}*start=NULL;




void creat(int *num)
{
      struct node *new_node,*current;

      new_node=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));


      new_node->data=num;
      new_node->next=NULL;

      if(start==NULL)
      {
      start=new_node;
      current=new_node;
      }
      else
      {
      current->next=new_node;
      current=new_node;
      }
}

main()
{

    int binrange,max=100,n,i,divi;
    clrscr();
    printf("enter range: ");
    scanf("%d",&binrange);
    n=max/binrange;
    divi=max/n;

    for(i=0;i<=max;i++)
    {
        if(i%divi==0 && i>0)
        {
            //create nodes here
            //store i into nodes
            creat(&i);

        }

    }

    getch();
}
```

Comment: `*start=NULL;` looks strange

Comment: *Where* do you get the warning?

Comment: is it wrong? start should be null for there is no connecting node yet.

Comment: @ForceBru There's nothing strange about it, it defines a pointer variable to the `struct`-type it also declares, and initializes it. Very common.

Comment: Oh, and [don't cast the return of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg at line ` new_node->data=num;`

Comment: how do i check if SLL is working?

Comment: You need to write one or more *tests* and run them. A function that prints your list is an Ok first test.

Comment: Why are you passing i by reference rather than by value?  With something so trivial, I wouldn't trade clarity ( needing to dereference the integer pointer to assign the data ) for speed.

Comment: Current is uninitialized (and should be removed and replaced by start)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new_node->data=num;
```

should be

```
new_node->data=*num;
```

`num` is a pointer and `*num` gives the value to be stored in the `new_node->data`

Assigning pointer to a variable of type `int` is giving a valid warning.

Comment: @imagineracoon Oh that is a different thing .. Keep the head of the list intact and print your list from head to end of list .. (Did you get what I just said?)

Comment: @imagineracoon Really that is a different thing all together you need to post another question with what you actually want

Comment: Ok. I will search about that. If nothing, ill post.